# List initialization - What changed in C++14?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, list-initialization

[image]These two lines from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

What is the difference between these two statements ? I don't see any difference

> **until c++14**
>
> If the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type with a default
> constructor, value-initialization is performed. Otherwise, if T is an
> aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.
>
> **since c++14**
>
> If T is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.
> Otherwise, if the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type with
> a default constructor, value-initialization is performed.

Comment: Thank You `@cigien` and `@StoryTeller` for edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is which one happens when both conditions apply: if *T* is an aggregate class (as opposed to an array), which certainly has a default constructor, **and** the *braced-init-list* is empty.  Of course, to understand why that matters, we then have to distinguish value initialization from aggregate initialization from an empty list.

Value initialization zero-initializes the object and then default-initializes it, which for an aggregate is default-initializing each of its members, so the value-initialization is member-wise (plus zeroing padding).  Aggregate initialization initializes each member from `{}`, which is again value initialization for many types but is **default initialization** for members of class type with a user-provided default constructor.  The difference can be seen in

```
struct A {A() {} int i;};
struct B {A a;};  // aggregate
B b{};     // i is 0 in C++11, uninitialized in C++14
B b2=B();  // i is 0 in both versions
```

In C++14 only, aggregates can have default member initializers; that can't contribute to a difference in behavior between the two language versions, of course, but it doesn't behave differently between these two rules anyway (since it replaces only the common default initialization).

Comment: Not all aggregates have a non-deleted default constructor (e.g., `struct X {const int x; };`).

Comment: @T.C.: That’s true, but whether the constructor is deleted isn’t considered here (except that of course the initialization may be ill-formed).  Or is that your point, that initializing such a type with `{}` is ill-formed in C++11 but not in C++14?

Comment: In N3337, the well-formedness [depends on whether `X`'s deleted default constructor is trivial](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#7.2) - which I think it is [under the definition at the time](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.ctor#5). If I'm reading the wiki notes correctly, [CWG1301](https://wg21.link/CWG1301) changed the definition of value-initialization to reject deleted constructors, and reordered the bullet to preserve the validity of `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the sequence of checking, so the aggregate type checking is taking place at the first place, and only then the rest.

Comment: And what effect does this change have?